# Setting dash-daq graph height in Python Dash Bootstrap Components

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash, plotly-python, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm new to Dashboard Development using Python Plotly and Dash. Also I have no background in CSS or html.
I'm trying to build a dashboard to show live and past data from a database in a dashboard. The data is fed by sensors attached to a raspi. I'm using Dash with bootstrap components to achieve a structure as shown below. I figured out to use Bootstrap Cards in columns as a container for each graph. As I don't like the looks of the go.Indicator Gauge Charts I tried using the dash daq one, which have their own problems with range, colors, missing labels etc.

The biggest problem I run into is that I'm not able to fit a gauge chart in a dbc.Card using percentage heights.

My code looks as follows:

```py
dbc.Row([dbc.Card([dbc.CardHeader(["Gauge"]), 
                 dbc.CardBody(
                        daq.Gauge(
                            color={"gradient":True ,"ranges":{"#ff0001": [0, 15], "ffff01":[15, 21], "green": [21, 22], "yellow" : [22,26], "#FF0000": [26,30] }},
                            showCurrentValue = True,
                            value=22,
                            scale={'interval': 2, 'labelInterval': 2},
                            max=30,
                            min=0,
                            style = {
                                     "height" : "80%"
                                     }
                            ) 
                
                )], style = {"height" : "50%"})
        ], className="border", style = {"height" : "50vh"})], style={"height": "100vh"})
```

the last style dict comming from the main div.
No matter what I am trying to change it always give me the following output somehow.

[dash daq Gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2boRS.png)

How can I adjust the height in relation to the dbc card it is contained in?

[Targeted Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zv8S.png)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am also struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-daq/graduatedbar) this can be easily solved by using the 'size' parameter, which I think is set in pixels. It can be fit into any card, regardless of its size, with this methid.

```
daq.Gauge(
    size=200,
    value=2,
    label='Default',

)
```

Comment: The OP was asking for a way to adjust the size of the component in relation to its parent component.